# How to get WebStorm to run ESLint ruletester efficiently

Tags: mocha.js, eslint, webstorm

I am writing an ESLint plugin and I have been testing with eslint.RuleTester.  This is okay, I know how to configure their test options argument but I always have to run the entire test file.

here is an example test file:

```js
const {RuleTester} = require('eslint');
const rulester = new RuleTester({setup});
const rule = require ('myrule');

//this works also but i have to run the entire file (and thus all the tests)
ruleTester.run('myruletest',rule,{invalid,valid});
```

Normally, when I install a test runner I get a run/configuration for it and handy `play`⏯ and `debug` buttons in line with each test. As I write more tests (particularly in the same file) it would be handy to quickly click a `=>` beside a test and run just that single test.

If I try to call `ruletester.run` from a `mocha.it` callback it will not report the test correctly (and definitely cannot debug / step into it).
e.g. this does not work well

```js
const mocha = require('mocha');
const {RuleTester} = require('eslint');
const rulester = new RuleTester({setup});
const rule = require ('myrule');

// nice play button and custom run configruation but not honest test feeback
it('mytest', ()=>{
   // it'll run this but will not report correctly -- `it` says it always passes
   ruleTester.run('myruletest, rule, {invalid,valid});
});


it('mytest', async ()=>{
  // async is of no help
   await ruleTester.run('myruletest, rule, {invalid,valid});
});

//this still works also but then i have to run the entire file (and thus all the tests)
ruleTester.run('myruletest',rule,{invalid,valid});
```

So how do I tell WebStorm to either

- recognize `eslint.RuleTester` as a testrunner
- properly call and instance of RuleTester from my own testrunner?

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing `eslint.RuleTester` as a test runner would require developing a special plugin.
See http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/ for basic documentation on plugin development. You can use existing plugins as example: Mocha runner is not fully open source, but its JavaScript part is open source (https://github.com/JetBrains/mocha-intellij); also, there is an open source plugin for Karma https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/js-karma

Comment: in lieu of that i'm thinking #2.... i'm optimistic of a way to configure ruletestor-- perhaps via the access `RuleTester.it` or `RuleTester.describe`.  or perhaps in the mocha configuration template that is provided....  the goal is that i can call `it` (globally) via the helpful UI buttons